# Cursor.hasNext throws java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
public String ForDate(String date) {
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(eq("date", date)).iterator();
    basicb b = new basicb();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
       b.setDepartament(cursor.next().getString("departament"));
       b.setText(cursor.next().getString("text"));
       b.setTitle(cursor.next().getString("title"));
       lista.add(b);
    }
}
```

I just want to do object from mongodb information but when I do this method get make some object but always return that errorjava.util.NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, the problem is that you are calling `next` method three times in a single loop. You should call it once and store its result in a variable, since `next` retrieves next element in the iteration

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
   Document element = cursor.next();
   b.setDepartament(element.getString("departament"));
   b.setText(element.getString("text"));
   b.setTitle(element.getString("title"));
   lista.add(b);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, im trying declate Type but need to import, what i should import? appear a big list xD

Comment: by `Type` I meant the type of the elements in the cursor - `Document`